# What is the effect "Blood oozes from you" on a Blood-Magic Blade?

Tags: diablo-iii

The [Blood-Magic Blade](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/bloodmagic-blade) is a craftable level 60 legendary dagger.  After the revamp of 1.0.4 legendaries, a new effect, described as "blood oozes from you" was added to the item description.

Given that the dagger looks like it still has incredibly low damage for a level 60 legendary, the only possible saving grace I could think of for this item is the effect.  However, I can't find any details of what it actually does.

What does "blood ooz[ing] from you" actually do?

Comment: Someone commented with this. "It means when you use the blade, you are likely holding the sharp edge rather than the handle. So blood oozes from your hand, really. Your intel must be high enough to be hold the dagger the right way." I'll keep looking but I think this might be it.

Comment: @Samjus - Oh, I thought that was a joke! You think they were serious?

Comment: @SaintWacko Who knows. Hard to tell now a days on the interwebz

Comment: And i'm dead tired so it could be a joke haha

Comment: I can't believe that nobody has figured this out yet. :/

Comment: Prolly just an effect like these: slorak, just a laugh sound when you die hollow whisper, cast haunt (WD SKill) to random enemy nearby butcher carver, butcher sound when you attack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everybody said, it's just pure visual effect.

Just purchased a cheap one from AH and tested it a bit. You don't *bleed*, you lose no health, you don't hold the dagger by the blade. All what **Blood oozes from you** does is purely visual effect that also leaves some (very)tiny blood spots on the ground for a short period of time.

Here are a few screenshots:

[image: Blood-Magic Blade effect]

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a purely visual effect. Many legendaries now have special effects when they are equipped. There are some boots (the name escapes me at the moment) that leave a trail of flame. I suspect this dagger leaves a trail of blood.

Comment: This seems like pure speculation.  The [Fire Walkers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fire-walkers) "burn the ground you walk on", but I was under the impression that this actually did damage. Few, if any, of the purely visual effects were added as an affix rather than being mentioned as flavor text.

Comment: Hm, you may be right, I'm just going by what I've read in some quick research. I didn't find anything definite.

Comment: Actually, in the last post [here](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6369198006), the poster says that it's just cosmetic. I don't know where he got that information, though.

Comment: That information was datamined before the patch was released, so I'm not sure how reliable it is. It did cause me to look at some other ilvl 61 crafted legendaries, though, and most of them really do look pretty bad compared to the dropped ones. Still... 216-225 DPS for an ilvl 61 legendary dagger?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty miserable. That dagger probably isn't even worth the crafting cost.

Comment: I can confirm that Fire Walkers do actual damage.  I can kill trash mobs in Act 1 Inferno just by running in circles around them (it takes 5-10 seconds), and I can walk through doors and other obstacles that need to be destroyed, as they break once I come into contact with them.

Answer (score 0):

I once wondered about this too. After researching a little bit on it and checking several different forums I've come to the conclusion that it's probably just a special effect to look "cool". I even looked on the wiki and it doesn't explain what the effect does at all. I don't think anyone really knows what the effect does, so we all come to the same conclusion that it's just a special looking effect for show. Sorry if I didn't help at all.

Answer (score -2):

the flavour text says "the taste of blood unleashes a magic few can control.", i read on another website that it apparently restores health per primary resource spent, but if it does, it's on a 1:1 ratio, as i cannot tell by its use (wearing as little armour as possible).

Comment: 1. Please don't guess, especially if there are already other answers and especially if the other answers tell the opposite. 2. If you read it on another website, please give a link to it. 3. Proper grammar is appreciated.

Comment: 1. i wasn't guessing, i was disproving a guess made in 2011 (and i found this slightly less old question more reasonable to revive the question). 2. my bad, but i can't find it. 3. my grammar is excellent, i just rarely capitalise because i don't think of the internet as formal.

Comment: 1. I have no idea what you mean by 2011, this question was asked in 2012 and the accepted answer written in 2013. With guess I mean "apparently", "if it does", "I cannot tell". 3. Using no capitalisation makes it hard to distinguish from crappy posts. And the internet isn't just one place, there are more and less serious websites. This one is a bit more on the serious side.